# Problem in getting Registration Id from C2DM in android

Tags: android

[C2DMReg] handleRequest caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x27ee68: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe

getting above error while getting registration key.....plz help me

Comment: hello please provide your full code we I can identify problem area.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/958901 this is the link where u can find my code. If i want to print Resgistration Key in logcat. so where i have to write log?i have already written into the Reciever Class but not able to get.

Comment: I check your code, I think there is not coding problem. It may be Environment setup problem or other, I am using Mac OS X for development and testing, I did test on Samsung Nexus S.

Answer (score 1):

just test it on real android froyo device or if you want testing on emulator than [use this link.](http://bhutiyagirish.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/testing-push-notification-android-market-in-emulator/)